# can someone explain this code in detail and how should I run it in my javascript program

Tags: javascript

In the code below, what is `i` and what is `c`? I want to use this code in my javascript so that I can move my map icon along a route.

How can I achieve this?

```
(function () 
{
  if (!map.me)
  {
    map.me = map.createLocationMarker(
      "http://libgmail.sourceforge.net/man.png", N.get("local"));
  };
  mv = function(i) 
  {
    c = map.directions.polyline.getPoint(i);
    map.recenterOrPanToLatLng(c);
    map.setMarkerPosition(map.me, N.get("local"), c); 
    if (i < map.directions.polyline.numPoints - 1)
    {
       window.setTimeout("mv("+(i+1) + ")",750)
    }
    else
    {
      map.me.hide()
    }
  };
  map.me.show();
  mv(0)
}
)();
```

Comment: You really should try to format your code so it's a bit readable. I made an attempt, I hope I didn't mangle it.

Comment: People who would like to help will probably want to know - what exactly are you trying to do, in what context and where did that code come from...

Answer (score 0):

c is a co-ordinate and i is an indexer, both are coming from the outer scope to which this code belongs.

Answer (score 0):

c - point in the map
i - integer parameter of function, that means number of point, starts with 0, every recursion loop increments by 1, ends by map.directions.polyline.numPoints - 1

This code shows the way across all points in map.directions.polyline